# maximum value of algebraic expression (another)

Tags: inequality, optimization, maxima-minima

if $p^2+q^2+r^2=5$ and  $p,q,r$ all are real number,

then maximum value of  $(4p-3q)^2+(5q-4r)^2+(5p-3r)^2$

what i try . Expanding $(4p-3q)^2+(5q-4r)^2+(5p-3r)^2$

$41p^2+41q^2+25r^2-24pq-40qr-30pr$

$25\times 5+16p^2+16q^2-24pq-40qr-30pr$

How i use inequality to find maximum of given expression

Help me please

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier

Comment: The  maximum is $250$, achieved at $p=-\frac{4}{\sqrt{5}},\ q
   =\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}},\ r=0$.

Comment: you expanded the thing incorrectly. For example, the coefficient of $p^2$ is actually $16+25=41$

Comment: Please check out [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). This is very much missing in context. Are you expected to just use some trickery (high school level tools extended for contests), did this come up in a multivariable calculus course when we could expect you to be familiar with Lagrange multipliers? Et cetera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll prove that $250$ it's a maximal value.

Indeed, 
$$250\geq(4p-3q)^2+(5q-4r)^2+(5p-3r)^2$$ it's 
$$50(p^2+q^2+r^2)\geq(4p-3q)^2+(5q-4r)^2+(5p-3r)^2$$ or
$$(3p+4q+5r)^2\geq0.$$
The equality occurs for $p^2+q^2+r^2=5$ and $3p+4q+5r=0.$